# How to reverse animate linearGradient on mouseout with inline SVG only

Tags: svg, inline, svg-filters, svg-animate, smil

I want to create a smooth reverse animation on the svg linearGradient on mouseout. Is this possible with inline code only (without js or css)?

I have tried the following code but after the first mouseover animation finished it reverts back to frame 1 which ruins the smooth mouseout effect.

On mouseout I want to reverse the linearGradient smoothly.

https://codepen.io/daneli84/pen/WNejrdd

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 360 160" width="360" height="160" id="ani">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="lightGradient">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="red">
<animate attributeName="stop-color" values="red; gold" dur=".5s" 
fill="freeze" begin="ani.mouseover" /> 
</stop>
<stop offset="90%" stop-color="gold">
</stop>
</linearGradient>
</defs> 
<circle cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="url(#lightGradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Expected results with using mouseout and a reverse linearGradient for a smooth reverse animation.

Comment: You may add a second `<animate>` element that `begin="ani.mouseout"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this. We animate one way on mouseenter and the reverse on mouseleave.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 360 160" width="360" height="160" id="ani">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="lightGradient">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="red">
<animate attributeName="stop-color" values="red; gold" dur=".5s" 
fill="freeze" restart = "whenNotActive" begin="ani.mouseenter" /> 
<animate attributeName="stop-color" values="gold; red" dur=".5s" 
fill="freeze" restart = "whenNotActive" begin="ani.mouseleave" /> 
</stop>
<stop offset="90%" stop-color="gold">
</stop>
</linearGradient>
</defs> 
<circle cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="url(#lightGradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect answer. mouseenter /mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout - my next question would be what is the difference but thank you kindly for the perfect answer! Another key element to your code is: restart = "whenNotActive" I have read up on this attribute here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/restart

Comment: mouseenter is more efficient for SVG as the circle can't have children.